# Azure AD B2C integration with SAML to SAP cloud platform

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We want to integrate B2C with SAP Cloud Platfrom. Therefore we need to setup an SAML IdP in B2C. Anyone have done this? There is an guide which I will follow if no one have done this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-sf-app-custom

Comment: This guide is pretty thorough. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/sap-hana-cloud-platform-identity-authentication-tutorial

Comment: This is AAD and based on the enterprise application which is in the store. I would love to make this via AAD B2C - which is quite different than AAD. Any ideas?